# Optic API vs CTS query performance

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10, marklogic-optic-api

I am using below two queries`(Optic and CTS)` to get the values for path-range index `/tXML/Item/PutawayCategory`.

**Query 1:** - It took approx. `4 milliseconds` to execute and return  17 distinct values. I tried executing  this same query multiple times.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace op="http://marklogic.com/optic"  at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";

op:from-lexicons(map:entry("PutawayCategory", cts:path-reference("/tXML/Item/PutawayCategory")))
=> op:where-distinct()
=> op:result()
```

**Query 2:** - It took approx. `0.30 milliseconds` to get the same result as `Query 1`

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";

cts:values(cts:path-reference("/tXML/Item/PutawayCategory"))
```

I am not getting why `Optic Query` is taking more time to execute than `cts` query.

Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your optic query to use `op:group-by("PutawayCategory")` instead of `op:where-distinct()` and it should perform much better.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace op="http://marklogic.com/optic"  at "/MarkLogic/optic.xqy";

op:from-lexicons(map:entry("PutawayCategory", cts:path-reference("/tXML/Item/PutawayCategory")))
=> op:group-by("PutawayCategory")
=> op:result()
```

With `op:from-lexicon`

> Optic emits rows based on co-occurrence of lexicon values within the same document similar to [`cts:value-tuples`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts:value-tuples).

This means that `op:from-lexicons()` is returning every instance of the values that are present in multiple documents, and can be returned multiple times, not a distinct list, and then `op:where-distinct()` is filtering and de-duplicating, which consumes CPU and time. The larger the set of values, the more work (and time) that `op:where-distinct()` has to do.

`cts:values()` is pulling a distinct list of values directly from the path-range-index lexicon, so there is less work to do.

There may be a way for MarkLogic to optimize the Optic query with `op:where-distinct()`. If you have access to MarkLogic Support, it would be helpful if you created a Support case inquiring about it.